# How to remove Extra dots from Django-filters?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-filter

I am filtering data using django-filters, but i am getting an extra `dots` in my dropdown, Please let me know How I can remove that Extra dots from my dropdown filters, I want to give the `lable` there but I am unable to do that, Please check my code and let me know How I can solve thsi issue.

here is my `filters.py` file...

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=Data_TYPE, field_name='data_type')
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['category', 'type', 'project_details__possession']
```

here is my `test.html` file where I am displaying the filters in dropdown...

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select hero__form-input form-control custom-select">
        {% render_field projectlist.form.category|attr:"type:select" class="hero__form-input form-control custom-select" onchange="this.form.submit()" %}
    </div>
   <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select hero__form-input form-control custom-select">
        {% render_field projectlist.form.type|attr:"type:select" class="hero__form-input form-control custom-select" onchange="this.form.submit()" %}
    </div>
   <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select hero__form-input form-control custom-select">
        {% render_field projectlist.form.project_details__possession|attr:"type:select" class="hero__form-input form-control custom-select" onchange="this.form.submit()" %}
    </div>
</form>
```

here is the image, where iwant to remove the `dots` and i want to replace with filter `lable`...
Plase check this `https://prnt.sc/vkif04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`empty_label`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=empty_label#choicefilter) parameter to set the value

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=Data_TYPE,
        field_name='data_type',
        empty_label="Any string you want to put"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['category', 'type']
```

Comment: its working perfect...but how i can do it with `related  model` fields, I updated my question with `project_details__possession`...where `project_details` is related model name and `possession` is fields name of related model...Please let me know how i can do it for `project_details__possession`

Comment: I am not sure about that since it is a related field. Better you ask a new question. Btw, please do accept and upvote this answer if you found this helpful to you.